# How to join multiple table's data in one GridView in ASP.Net Webform on button_click

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linq-to-entities

I am populating all Transaction data on one button click in a GridView. However, Transaction table in the database does  not contain Dimension table (e.g. Account table) data such as Transaction table contains AccountID but it does not have AccountName property which I have to bring from the Account table. In the DataAccess layer the method (GetAllTransactions()) does contain the join between Transaction and Account table on AccountID, but when I try to select account.AccountName it does not work.

I just need to show few tables from Transaction table where the AccountID mataches and show the AccountName column instead of AccountID from the Transaction table.

The DataAccess method looks like:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Transaction>GetAllTransactions()
    {
        List<Transaction> allTransactions = new List<Transaction>();
        using (var context = new CostReportEntities())
        {
            allTransactions = (from t in context.Transactions
                               join account in context.Accounts on t.AccountID equals account.AccountID
                               select t).ToList();
        }          
        return allTransactions;
    }
```

and the Code behind the .aspx page is as follows:

```
    protected void _UIButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions = ts.GetAllTransactions();
        _UITransactionGridView.DataSource = transactions;
        _UITransactionGridView.DataBind();
        _UITransactionGridView.PageIndex = 0;

    }
```

tried few things with the following also, but I am not getting the LINQ idea. The following gives error.

```
...select new {t.*, account.AccountName}).ToList();
```

I need a direction which way should I be looking at to make the task work to populate data from multiple tables in one GridView. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since my Model for Transaction did not have any property of Account table I had to create a ViewModel type class which returns custom data of AccountNumber for every Transaction.

Tha code that I used to solve the problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837694/1108500)