# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<modelClass>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to populate Transaction data where AccountNumber does not exist. I need to access the Account table to get that. I am getting the following error where I am trying to return IEnumerable

Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<ProjectModel.Transaction>`

The error is shown on top of **.ToList();** part of the code. What am I doing wrong?

the code is:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Transaction>GetAllTransactions()
    {
       List<Transaction> allTransactions = new List<Transaction>();
        using (var context = new CostReportEntities())
        {
            allTransactions = (from t in context.Transactions
                               join acc in context.Accounts on t.AccountID equals acc.AccountID
                               where t.AccountID == acc.AccountID
                               select new 
                               {
                                   acc.AccountNumber,
                                   t.LocalAmount
                               }).ToList();

        }
        return allTransactions;

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List of anonymous types cannot be casted to list of transactions. Looks like your `Transaction` class do not have `AccountNumber` property. Also you cannot return anonymous objects from methods. So you should create some type which will hold required data:

```
public class AccountTransaction
{
    public int LocalAmount { get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And return these objects:

```
public static IEnumerable<AccountTransaction> GetAllTransactions()
{       
    using (var context = new CostReportEntities())
    {
        return (from t in context.Transactions
                join acc in context.Accounts 
                     on t.AccountID equals acc.AccountID              
                select new AccountTransaction {
                     AccountNumber = acc.AccountNumber,
                     LocalAmount = t.LocalAmount
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

*BTW* you don't need duplicate join condition in where filter

Comment: This worked perfectly. Excellent answer. Thanks a lot for putting me in right direction.Doing this I have learnt few other things too. Now I know what ViewModel is all about.

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous type which you're projecting in the "select new" section of your Linq query cannot be casted directly to your "Transaction" type.

Instead, you should project a new instance of Transaction.  The following might help:

```
allTransactions = (from t in context.Transactions
    join acc in context.Accounts on t.AccountID equals acc.AccountID
    where t.AccountID == acc.AccountID
    select new Transaction()
    {
        AccountNumber = acc.AccountNumber,
        LocalAmount = t.LocalAmount
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This would not work because I don't have AccountNumber property in Transaction table.

Comment: Maybe list the properties of your poco class next time, too? :)

Comment: That is definitely a good idea, I will definitely remember this next time. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No problem shaz - Apologies if I was snarky, haven't had my coffee yet :)

Comment: not at all, at least I could understand that I can't use this code because the property was not there. But definitely I can do this when Entities have similar properties.So nothing is in waste.